# read coordinates from a file in c

Tags: c, file, file-io, string-parsing

I have to read coordinates from a file in c in order to calculate the distance between two points.

How to read the following input from a file?

```
(25, 4) (1, -6)
(2 ,3) (2,34)
```

Comment: Can you post the code you have so far?

Comment: Please post your own attempts and problems so far ... nobody here is interested to do your homework for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use your file as it is but you are going to need  kind of messy *String Processing*. In order to get the individual numbers you have to get rid of the *brackets* and the *comma*..

Rather I would suggest you to change the way you save the points to your file.
rather than putting the points [*in your file*] like this:
 **(25, 4) (1, -6)**

Put them like this:
 **25 4 1 -6**

Then you can simply say:

```
fscanf(fp,"%d%d%d%d,&x1,&y1,&x2,&y2);
```

To get the two points.